# Can't import logging.handlers inside a nose test

Tags: python, importerror, nose

I'm writing a basic test with nose to call a single function from a logging wrapper, but once I got the test to be discovered I started getting standard library module import errors.

This is the code I'm trying to write some tests for and has been in production and hasn't changed in a long time, so I'm sure the there's something wrong when how I'm trying to use nose.

```
  Failure: ImportError (cannot import name WatchedFileHandler) ... ERROR

  ======================================================================
  ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name WatchedFileHandler)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 389, in loadTestsFromName
      module = self.importer.importFromPath(
    File "/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
      return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
    File "/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
      mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
    File "/Users/jolson/project/qworker/tests/unit/test_qscript_log.py", line 2, in ?
      from logging.handlers import WatchedFileHandler, TimedRotatingFileHandler
  ImportError: cannot import name WatchedFileHandler
```

What could cause this?

**Update:**
I've simplified it to the following and the test still fails, but outside of nose, this all works as expected.

```
from logging.handlers import WatchedFileHandler, TimedRotatingFileHandler

def test_INFO():
    assert 0 == 0
```

** Update 2 **
I've checked my paths. Inside the nosetests, my path looks like this.

```
['/Users/jolson/project/qworker/tests', '/Users/jolson/project/qworker',
'/opt/local/bin', '/opt/local/lib/python24.zip', '/opt/local/lib/python2.4', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.4/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/lib/python2.4/plat-mac', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.4/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/lib/python2.4/lib-tk',
 '/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/readline', '/opt/local/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload', 
'/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages', '/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg-info']
```

but my normal path inside the python interpreter is

```
['', '/usr/local/bin', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.8.2-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-3.6-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/stevedore-0.3-py2.7.egg', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_clone-0.2.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

I'm running `nosetests-2.4 tests`

which has one file in `tests/unit/test_log.py`

Comment: with what command do you run nose? (so I can do exactly the same)

Comment: have a look at `logging.__file__` and append the basename to the path to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My os was defaulting to `nosetests-2.4` which uses python 2.4, but all our code is python 2.7, so that's why the path was wrong and nothing was working and logging.handlers was just the first package that was missing from 2.4 libs that was needed.

Comment: I'm completely baffled why it was doing that though.

Comment: How do you actually fix this?  Add your environment to python path?

Comment: I fixed it by making sure the 2.7 version of nosetest was being used.  I think I just uninstalled nosetest-2.4 in this case.